# Recompile the proxy class bytes[] (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.class) in memory to a general $Proxy0.java file

Tags: java-8, proxy, java-native-interface

In JDK specific proxy class was generate by below code in Proxy.java

```
      /*
             * Generate the specified proxy class.
             */
            byte[] proxyClassFile = ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(
                proxyName, interfaces, accessFlags);
            try {
                return defineClass0(loader, proxyName,
                                    proxyClassFile, 0, proxyClassFile.length);
            } catch (ClassFormatError e) {
```

Now I have been acquire the byte[] proxyClassFile and I want use JNI function defineClass0 and regenerate the specific proxy.

Error as below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: util.DefineClass.cloader.defineClass0(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at util.DefineClass.cloader.defineClass0(Native Method)

My file as below：

Test.java

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       ]
        Class testc;
        Object testo;
        cloader cl=new cloader();
        testc=cl.load("com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0");
        testo=testc.newInstance();
        ....

    }
}
```

cloader.java

```
class cloader extends ClassLoader {
    public native Class<?> defineClass0(ClassLoader loader, String name,
                                        byte[] b, int off, int len);
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("java");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static int returnActualLength(byte[] data) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == '\0')
            { break;}
        }
        return i;
    }

public Class load(String classname) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try {

            Class ctmp=this.findLoadedClass(classname);
            System.out.println(ctmp.getName()+ " is load");
            return ctmp;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        byte[] classbyte = {........};

        int readsize;
        readsize=returnActualLength(classbyte);

        return defineClass0(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0",classbyte, 0, readsize);//there be error 

    }
}
```

My target is recompile the proxy class bytes[] (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.class) in memory to a general $Proxy0.java file

Comment: When you declare a `native` method, you have to implement that method somehow, e.g. via native code. You can’t just declare a method and expect it to magically do whatever you intended. Besides that “recompile class bytes to a .java file” makes no sense. Neither does “… in memory … to a file”. Besides that, when you extend a `ClassLoader`, you inherit usable `defineClass` methods. But note that assuming that the first zero byte marks the end of a class file will never work. And still, it’s unclear what you actually are trying to achieve.

Comment: Great thanks! Very clear now !I have been solved this problem.My purpose is get the code structure of $proxy0 ,and know how Proxy works exactly when it proxy a interface ,why the invocationhandle's method invoke be invoked first when we call the function of interface(which be proxied) .  I will paste my journey tomorrow.

Comment: @Holger If the native method only could be called by the special java code? Or we could call native method bind with one special Class when we define native method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject.java

```
public interface Subject {
    public void rent();

    public void hello(String str);

    public void methodNotImpl();
}
```

ProxyGeneratorUtils.java //To save the proxy class file to local.

```
public class ProxyGeneratorUtils {
    public static void writeProxyClassToHardDisk(String path) {
        byte[] classFile = ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass("$Proxy0", RealSubject.class.getInterfaces());

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            out.write(classFile);
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
@Test
public void testGenerateProxyClass() {
 ProxyGeneratorUtils.writeProxyClassToHardDisk("/Desktop/temp/$Proxy0.class";
    }
}
```

Decompile the $Proxy0.class use some tool and acquire the 
$Proxy0.java

```
import com.AnotherExample.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public final class $Proxy0 extends Proxy implements Subject
{
    private static Method m1;
    private static Method m4;
    private static Method m5;
    private static Method m2;
    private static Method m3;
    private static Method m0;

    public $Proxy0(final InvocationHandler invocationHandler) {
        super(invocationHandler);
    }

    public final boolean equals(final Object o) {
        try {
            return (boolean)super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m1, new Object[] { o });
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    public final void rent() {
        try {
            super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m4, null);//*****
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    public final void methodNotImpl() {
        try {
            super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m5, null);
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    public final String toString() {
        try {
            return (String)super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m2, null);
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    public final void hello(final String s) {
        try {
            super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m3, new Object[] { s });
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    public final int hashCode() {
        try {
            return (int)super.h.invoke(this, $Proxy0.m0, null);
        }
        catch (Error | RuntimeException error) {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }

    static {
        try {
            $Proxy0.m1 = Class.forName("java.lang.Object").getMethod("equals", Class.forName("java.lang.Object"));
            $Proxy0.m4 = Class.forName("com.AnotherExample.Subject").getMethod("rent", (Class<?>[])new Class[0]);
            $Proxy0.m5 = Class.forName("com.AnotherExample.Subject").getMethod("methodNotImpl", (Class<?>[])new Class[0]);
            $Proxy0.m2 = Class.forName("java.lang.Object").getMethod("toString", (Class<?>[])new Class[0]);
            $Proxy0.m3 = Class.forName("com.AnotherExample.Subject").getMethod("hello", Class.forName("java.lang.String"));
            $Proxy0.m0 = Class.forName("java.lang.Object").getMethod("hashCode", (Class<?>[])new Class[0]);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new NoSuchMethodError(ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex2) {
            throw new NoClassDefFoundError(ex2.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java //For reference

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Subject realSubject = new RealSubject();
        InvocationHandler handler = new DynamicProxy(realSubject);//handler own the realSubject's information

        Subject subject = (Subject) Proxy.newProxyInstance(handler.getClass().getClassLoader(), realSubject
                .getClass().getInterfaces(), handler);

        System.out.println(subject.getClass().getName());
        subject.rent();
        subject.hello("world");
        subject.methodNotImpl();
    }
}
```

Through these steps we know how Proxy work exactly，
No matter what function defined in the interface we called, **$proxy0 will first call the invoke function super.h.invoke(){}**;

We could pass the interface’s Method information to the InvocationHandler object(which used to construct the proxy).

Then we could do anything （include call the interface's function ）in the function super.h.invoke(){} .

If we want call realSubject’s function we just need use the polymorphism pass an RealSubject object through method.invoke(realSubject, args);

Please know this accomplished only calling the Subject interface's function and proxy the object rather than an Class

Comment: It’s not clear what new insights this has given you, besides that the generated code does exactly what [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) said.